Sending Traceability Logs to a Different File Than the Default Keycloak Log File
Want to log some traces on a specific file with log rotation.
<keycloak.version>21.1.1</keycloak.version>
I created a class called TracabilityLogger that logs certain traces I retrieve from Keycloak events. I want to send them to a specific file.
I tried adding a Logback configuration, but it does not seem compatible with the Quarkus instantiation using JBoss. Maybe I need to enable the quarkus-logging-logback extension. Does anyone know how to do this? I have the impression that Keycloak does not allow it and crashes when attempting to add the extension. Any other ideas?
